# Template Parameter Pack Fails on Clang but not VS 2015

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I'm working on a function which invokes a supplied function with a variable number of arguments. It compiles and works correctly on Visual Studio 2015, but fails to compile on Clang . I've prepared a demonstration which shows what I'm trying to do.  The error I get in Clang is:

> prog.cpp: In function 'int main()': prog.cpp:31:2: error: no matching
>   function for call to 'run(std::vector&, void (*)(int&, const
>   int&), const int&)'   );   ^ prog.cpp:7:6: note: candidate:
>   template void
>   run(std::vector&, const std::function&,
>   mutrArgs ...)  void run(
>         ^ prog.cpp:7:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: prog.cpp:31:2: note:   mismatched types 'const
>   std::function' and 'void (*)(int&, const
>   int&)'   );

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<int RepeatTimes, class ... mutrArgs>
void run(
    vector<int>& vec,
    const function<void(int&, mutrArgs ...)>& mutr,
    mutrArgs ... args
)
{
    for (int times{0} ; times < RepeatTimes ; ++times)
        for (auto& item : vec)
            mutr(item, args...);
}

void adder(int& i, const int& val)
{
    i += val;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    const int addValue{4};
    run<2, const int&>(
        v,
        &adder,
        addValue
    );
    for (auto i : v)
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `std::function`, make the type a template too, like all [standard algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: In the non demonstration function, it's required to take a set number of arguments.

Comment: If you use `std::function<void(int&,const int&)>(&adder)` it compiles.  Not sure why it needs to be specified though.  Might have to do with the pack part not being deducible but I am uncertain of the rules.

Comment: Or if you pass by function pointer for `run<2, const int&>`, it works too [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/111376b79c4be452)

Comment: using `std::function<decltype(adder)>(adder)` compile with clang++ 3.5 and with g++ 4.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`run<2, const int&>` just state the first argument, but doesn't deactivate deduction.

```
run<2, const int&>(v, &adder, addValue);
```

has 2 places to deduce `mutrArgs`:

- `addValue` -> `mutrArgs` = `{ const int& }`
- `&adder` which is not a `std::function` and so fail.

Taking address of function fix that problem

```
auto call_run = &run<2, const int&>;
call_run(v, &adder, addValue);
```

Strangely, clang doesn't support the inlined usage contrary to gcc :/

```
(&run<2, const int&>)(v, &adder, addValue);
```

If you want to disable deduction, you may make your template arg non deducible:

```
template <typename T> struct identity { using type = T; };

template <typename T> using non_deducible_t = typename identity<T>::type;
```

And then

```
template<int RepeatTimes, class ... mutrArgs>
void run(
    std::vector<int>& vec,
    const std::function<void(int&, non_deducible_t<mutrArgs> ...)>& mutr,
    non_deducible_t<mutrArgs> ... args
)
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2dd0bdb984de602)

Even if in your case a simple `typename F` as suggested by Joachim Pileborg seems better.

Comment: To get it to finally compile correctly on clang I needed to do both, get the function address and use the deducing template.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at all [standard library algorithm function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), at least the ones taking a "predicate" (a callable object) they take that argument as a templated type.

If you do the same it will build:

```
template<int RepeatTimes, typename F, class ... mutrArgs>
void run(
    vector<int>& vec,
    F mutr,
    mutrArgs ... args
)
{
    ...
}
```

See [here for an example of you code](http://ideone.com/xSp3q9). Note that you don't need to provide all template arguments, the compiler is able to deduce them.

Comment: This circumvents the required usage, and would certainly work of course.